# How to navigate between screens in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

How to navigate between screens in ReactJS?

When all the time I tried to run my code, it didn't work. As I'm new to ReactJS, still I couldn't find a proper solution. I'm glad if someone can give some answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "screens" ? If you want to navigate between your components you have to use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)

Comment: You should add what you have tried, what you expect it to do, and what happened instead along with some code examples. That being said, give react-router-dom a try, I find it makes this all fairly easy. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start